# Как получить координаты границ?

Tags: c#, yandex-static-maps-api

Добрые сутки, необходимо получить координаты полигона границы области, в GeoObject они не возвращается, есть ли какой-то другой метод? https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/ - с помощью этого получаю xml передав geocode, чтоб можно было передать для от рисовки в static Яндекс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: API не возвращают границы административных единиц